# Long file names in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm using App Engine to upload files to Google Cloud Storage via the Blobstore API. The thing is that when I explore the files in the Google Developer Console, this long names appear:

[image: Console screenshot]

Why is this ? Do am I doing something wrong ?

It's something trivial because I'm able to work perfectly with the files, I was just curious about it.
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, that's the blobstore key of your file. It's totally normal and to be expected.

You can see a user in Google's [Public Issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11338&q=rename%20file&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log) that was asking for a way to rename the file because he found the blobstore name confusing.